# Android Eclipse Querying thumbnails of images stored outside of gallery

Tags: android, eclipse, image, thumbnails, mediastore

Are you able to use MediaStore's queryMiniThumbnails method on images that you store in a custom location (for example /sdcard/testimages)?

When you add a new image to that custom location, does it automatically generate a thumbnail, or is that something I would have to do as I am adding the photos?

Answer (score 2):

After you store the image in your custom location, you can call [MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(String path, String mimeType)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to have it added right away. I believe this *should* add it to the Gallery and thus generate a thumbnail for it. You could then use the queryMiniThumbnails method.

There's also a convenience version of scanFile with a callback that sets up the MediaScannerConnection for you and implements a callback so you can operate on the results when it is done:
 [scanFile(Context context, String[] paths, String[] mimeTypes, MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener callback)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html#scanFile%28android.content.Context,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20android.media.MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener%29)

Please give this a try. I haven't tested this exact workflow so not sure if it will work out.